# May attributive "church" always be replaced with "ecclesiastical"?

Tags: word-usage

Trying to translate *church tradition* in Italian, I noticed that I would translate it as *tradizione della chiesa* (literally, "tradition of the church"), or *tradizione ecclesiale* (literally, "ecclesiastical tradition").

Is using *ecclesiastical* instead of *church* as attributive always correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. *Ecclesiastical* refers only to what pertains to churches generally, or to a church (or the Church) as an institution, or to an *ecclesiastic* (an officer or minister of the church) or to *ecclesiastics* generally.

> Simony is financial traffic in ecclesiastical office.
>   The chasuble is an item of ecclesiastical dress.
>   Rev. Sartorius has been tardy in discharge of his ecclesiastical duties.

But a *church* may be a specific building or congregation, and in this case you would not refer to whatever pertains to it as *ecclesiastical*. A *church member* is not an *ecclesiastical member*, a *church yard* is not an *ecclesiastical yard*, and a *church porch* is not an *ecclesiastical porch*. On the other hand:

> This church porch is an outstanding example of 14th century ecclesiastical architecture.

Comment: Is there a word missing in the example beginning, "Simony..."?

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff I don't think so - oh. No, *traffic in ecclesiastical office* means *purchase and sale of ecclesiastical positions*, as in *traffic in drugs*.

Comment: Ah I see; sorry; wasn't familiar with the term, and I thought Simony was a person :-)

Comment: And even when dealing with the a specific church, "ecclesiastical" is a rather formal term relating to functions or offices with an overtly religious nature. One can talk about a church picnic, or a church supper, or a church softball league, but an ecclesiastical picnic would sound very odd.